# Dreamweaver centering background

Tags: dreamweaver

How do you center the background image on Dreamweaver CS5?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to center it horizontally, in the css for the element

> background-repeat: repeat-y;
>
> background-position: center;

Answer (score 1):

You can use either depending on how you like to markup:

```
background-position:center;

background: url(name.jpg) center;
```